# Qt Creator is unable to compile extern "C" block with C incompatible code

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qmake

I'm using Qt Creator for a project in C++ and a few of the headers contain extern "C" blocks with function declarations that contain C incompatible code such as default parameters and the use of bool/true/false.

I'm using Qt 5.11 on Ununtu 5.11.

Here's an example snippet of the extern block:

```
#ifdef __cpluscplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    int foo (int param1, int param2, int param3=0);

    bool bar(int param);

#ifdef __cpluscplus
}
#endif
```

This would result in the following compile errors respectively:

```
file.h: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘=’ token

file.h: error: unknown type name ‘bool’
```

This compiles with no issues with a Makefile but when I use qmake with Qt Creator I get these errors. I'm unable to change this header because it is checked in code that is in use.

I have a Qt project that I'm trying to integrate with an existing code base which I can't modify.

Please let me know what my options are? Turning off the "__cplusplus" flag?

Comment: I tried that it didn’t work. The bigger problem is that it’s in an extern “C” block.

Comment: So the in this case __cplusplus flag is put around the extern C opening and closing. Not sure why it was done like this. As you can see above.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. It works with a plain Makefile, as you say. Clearly, there is something wrong in the way you are using Qt Creator, that it is trying to compile the code as C. You need to tell us a little more about how you created the project in Qt Creator, and maybe include the project's qmake `.pro` file.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming all your code is C++ code in "*.cpp" files, remove the `extern "C"` block.

The meaning of `extern "C"` block is to tell the C++ compiler to treat the code within the block as C. Clearly the function declarations `foo` and `bar` are C++, not C.

The `__cplusplus` macro is defined by the compiler (gcc, clang, etc.) and is part of the C++ standard.

If possible, seek clarifications from whoever wrote "file.h" and the existing codebase.

Comment: [`extern "C"`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage) does _not_ tell the compiler to treat the code as C. The compiler is treating the whole file as C for some other reason.

Comment: From the information provided by OP, this is the best I could attempt. I can't comment because I don't have enough reputation. Does downvoting help here?